# How are data types related to information theory?

Tags: programming-languages, information-theory

I was just reading from wikipedia the following about [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information):

> From the stance of information theory, information is taken as a
>   sequence of symbols from an alphabet, say an input alphabet χ, and an
>   output alphabet ϒ. Information processing consists of an input-output
>   function that maps any input sequence from χ into an output sequence
>   from ϒ. The mapping may be probabilistic or determinate. It may have
>   memory or be memoryless.

I'm just guessing here, but is the input alphabet the two states of a bit (0 and 1) and the output alphabet governed by the datatypes of the executing program when those bits are accessed?

Comment: That definition is just wrong: it describes data, not information.

Comment: sounds like this question should be deleted

Comment: @AaronAnodide I don't see any reason to delete this question. If you're confused about that article, others may be.

Answer (score 5):

**Interpretation: The Link Between Data Types and Information Theory**
I believe the missing link between these two topics, information theory and data types, is interpretation. Interpretation is essentially the "input-output function" for which output (meaning) is derived from input (data). Whether the interpretation is being performed by a computer, at compile-time or run-time, or a human is relative to the task at hand.

At any rate, data types are language-defined/user-defined interpretations of an input alphabet to an output alphabet. Also, language-defined data types usually have a direct relation to the size of storage locations on a computer.

**Probabilistic vs. Deterministic "Mapping"**
When determining the output based on a given input, is the output definite (deterministic) or is the output uncertain/ambiguous (probabilistic)?

**Memory vs. Memoryless "Mapping"**
When determining the output based on a given input, does the determining process require memory?